# How to get a correct xpath for use in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: xpath

[The image in the link directs to the line where my target information is placed]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghXcX.png) I'm trying to get a correct xpath and use it with IMPORTXML function.

what i need is "22.09.20"

That's what i get when i copy the xpath of the object on the website
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghXcX.png)/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]

IMPORTXML function returns N/A

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. 
Can you provide a sample of the html you are trying to use xpath on ?
Moreover, the XPath string you are using is really difficult to read because there are only div. Are you creating the HTML yourself or trying to parse an existing page ? You could do better by using classes and id.

Comment: <span class="cardMainInfo__content">22.09.2020 </span>
This right here is the exact line of code that contains the required string (22.09.2020)
I'm parsing an existing page

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the url?

Comment: Alright, made some changes
Thanks for the efforts, i'm feeling pretty stupid for being this close to solving the problem and failing miserably

Comment: Unfortunately, an image doesn't help. If you want people to help you, you'll need to post the actual url.

Comment: https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ok504/view/common-info.html?regNumber=0173200001420000972&backUrl=8ea10cf1-d7d2-4000-82ab-3b5cf88c6aac

Comment: That page is dynamically loaded using javascript. GS can't handle it. You'll need a tool like Selenium.

Comment: Just what i thought
Anyway, appreciate your help